# Can I use Auto-away with just a Nest Protect, so no Thermostat? (NEST-API)

Tags: nest-api

I'm trying to request the home/away/auto-away status of my NEST Protect (Smoke+CM) wired version by using the NEST API with a REST call like this:

curl -L -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" "https://developer-api.nest.com/structures/Zwdy.../away?auth=c.uR..."

(where "Zwdy..." is my structure id. Note that I shortend the structure id and the auth code for clarity)

It returns "home" so that seems to work fine! Except that it always returns "home" even if I haven't been in the room for a day or so. Note that I only own a Protect, so no thermostat!
Any hints on what I might be doing wrong?

I did some research and it appears it should be possible to use home/away/auto-away with just the Protect. Or is this incorrect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-Away works by having the devices in the house vote on the the occupancy status, since the Nest Protect does not maintain a real time connection to Nest's service, it can't participate in or initiate the voting. The Protect will upload historical motion data to the cloud every day, to be used in Auto-Away voting in the future.

Thus, there is no concept of an Auto-Away state in a Nest Protect only household.

Comment: Thanks David, that makes a lot of sense. At least for the battery powered version of Protect. NEST claims that the wired version does a more frequent update so I would assume that it does have a real time connection to the Nest service? Do you have any information on that?

Comment: The wired version is still not real time, and because it has no need of home/away state it does not have the logic to participate in that process. (You still want to set off the alarm even if the device thinks no one is around to hear, just in case)